# PyQT6 QWebEngineView low performance

Tags: python, browser, pyqt6

I'm trying to create a very simple custom browser for a local app that will only be running on a single machine and will have restrictions for the users like disabling redirection. Everything works as expected except the animation part. The animations look really choppy with really low fps, but are really simple (I only use animations on resizing divs when selected). The machine I'm working on has:
Intel i7 8700 3.2
SSD
4GB NVidia GeForce GTX 1070
16GB Ram

The animations work great on firefox and chrome but not on my PyQT6 browser.

The code I use for the browser:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")

page = "C:/xampp/htdocs/app"

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showFullScreen()
        path = os.path.abspath(page)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("file:\\"+path))
        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('App')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing some important information?
Thanks in advance

## EDIT

An example would be somehting like this: [Simple Jquery animation](https://codepen.io/thanos-pakou/pen/ZEraNVL). The bigger the div gets the choppier the animation. I also noticed that if I run this animation through chrome cpu usage goes 5-6% maximum. Through QWebEngine though, it goes around 45-55%.

Comment: you should add link with animation so we could test it with your code.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I added a codepen link. Thanks for the answer. @furas

Comment: animation works correctly when I run your code with your URL on my 10 years old laptop. But it really use ~60% CPU when animation is running and ~0% when animation is finished.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the quick response and testing. Well, I'm pretty sure that I have to either optimize it somehow or try a different approach. The thing is that this web engine is really easy to setup and very convenient except the perfomance part. I really don't know how to proceed at this point.